# Mock get method of dictionary - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am using MagicMock to create a mock object and make it behave like dictionary like this:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> m = mock.MagicMock()
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> m.__getitem__.side_effect = d.__getitem__
>>> m['foo']
'bar'
>>> m.get('foo')
<MagicMock name='mock.get()' id='140668601658096'>
```

How can I get **bar** value with get method as well?

Comment: Just add `m.get.side_effect = d.get`?

Comment: What's the point of this? What are you doing that you think mocking a dict would be a solution to? Aside from that, @rdas is correct, the MagicMock has no behavioiur other than returning sub-mocks. Any behavioural divergence you have to handroll.

Comment: @Masklinn I had a dictionary object in my code that was using get method and I needed to mock its value and get.return_value was not getting it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__getitem__` magic method and `get` method are not the same.

In your example you are mocking only the `__getitem__` magic method so the `m['foo']` works as expected.

If you want to use the `get()` method you should also mock that.

**Mock `get()` method:**

```
from unittest import mock
m = mock.MagicMock()
d = {'foo': 'bar'}
m.get.side_effect = d.get
print(m.get('foo'))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
bar
```